# Using android Intent to launch my application in background

Tags: android, filter, android-intent

Is it possible to launch two applications with one Intent? For example, broadcast intents fire those who are listening to them.

My idea is to run a watcher while user is browsing websites using android browser. So far, my searches tell me to use intent filter to capture ACTION_VIEW with data "http" or "https". But this isn't what I needed. It will ask users whether they want to use my application to complete action.

Any suggestions would welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run something in background, use `Service`. If you need to have `Activity` and `Service` running simultaneously, then start you "watcher" `Service` in `onCreate()` and stop it in `onDestroy()`.

You then will need to handle only Activity intent and user will not need to choose anything.

Comment: Ohh. I see what you means. Sorry I am a bit slow.
Let me check with you something. Is it possible to watch other application activity from my service? In other word,is it possible to get the Intent Data from my service if the user uses android browser to surf net? If so, how would I do that? 
FYI, I need to intercept before the content get delivered to browser.